How to get all content from active window using AccessibilityService
How can i get all content from screen when i update window? is this possible?
Means when i open and close any application, also home screen of device i want to get all text from active window.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewLongClicked|typeViewSelected|typeViewFocused|typeViewTextChanged|typeWindowStateChanged|typeNotificationStateChanged|typeViewHoverEnter|typeViewHoverExit|typeTouchExplorationGestureStart|typeTouchExplorationGestureEnd|typeWindowContentChanged|typeViewScrolled|typeViewTextSelectionChanged|typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds|flagRequestFilterKeyEvents|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="false"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canTakeScreenshot="true"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" />


There is documentation on retrieving content in an accessibility service. What have you tried, and what specific problems did you encounter?

Let it be specific, I to developer some feature like Translator Chat, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zaz.translate

the one image display over any application and if image detect any text over active window then need to translate it to specific language.

You can check it via install reference link.

What CommonsWare is asking is what have you tried doing? You have to show where you are having problems. Check the link he gave for retrieving content from accessibility service.

To retrieve all texts from current screen from accessibility service, you can use following method:
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) {
     AccessibilityNodeInfo root = getRootInActiveWindow();
     if (root != null) {
         List<String> allTexts = getAllTexts(root); // This array contains all texts present on screen
     }
}

// This traverses all the node tree and get the nodes' text recursively
public List<String> getAllTexts(AccessibilityNodeInfo node) {
    ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
    if (node == null) {
        return texts;
    }
    if (node.getText() != null && node.getText() != "") {
        texts.add(node.getText());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
        texts.addAll(getAllTexts(node.getChild(i)));
    }
    return texts;
}

This assumes that you have correctly set up your accessibility service and allowed it properly from settings. Also, traversing the root node after every accessibility event is very degrading for performance, so you should do it on special conditions and not every time an event is sent. Because Accessibility Services receives many events very fast.
